# What is the noop function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I found in an article on function `.noop()`, which in this library should be included. What is doing? Just call fallbacks? How to use this function?

> This method does not accept any arguments.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.noop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it does state in the docs:

> This is useful for plugin authors who offer optional callbacks; in the case that no callback is given, something like jQuery.noop could execute.

Probably a fast way to create a default function. And as an added bonus, without creating an anonymous function every time that function is called.

```
function aFunctionThatAcceptsACallback(callback){
  callback = callback || jQuery.noop;

  // do something

  // safely call callback, regardless if the function received any
  callback();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

$.noop() is an empty function which returns nothing.

In another word, it's just equivalent to this:

```
$.noop => function () {}//returns nothing
```

It has nothing to do with the function so it no longer requires to accept arguments.